# How to generate PDF from API

Tags: c#, entity-framework, itext, wkhtmltopdf, html-to-pdf

In our project, we are using API with c# Entity Framework. Need to trigger mail notification along with attached PDF. Can someone explain me how to create pdf in api side with data binding from repository.

Comment: To clarify your question, you need to extend your API to create an email with an attachment, that attatchment being a PDF?

Comment: This is sort of two questions at once  here (pdf generation + email trigger). Regarding PDF conversion, this is a duplicate of [your other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72906723/how-to-convert-html-to-pdf-in-api) – btw, cross-posting is never nice ;) – so maybe rephrase this question to only ask about the email notification part.