# How to convert html to pdf in API

Tags: itext, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf, html-to-pdf, openhtmltopdf

I want to generate pdf from API Side. I already created html files. Can someone explain me how to convert html to pdf?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Could you make your question more specific i.e. what framework / programming language (i guess it's Java or C# from the `itext` tag) is your API in? Add that to the tag list so people can help you better. And – is there a conversion library that you are already using? If you're spoiled for choice, the question "Which Html-to-PDF converter to use for {languageXXX}?" may be a good thread on it's own.

Comment: You can try this API: https://apistax.io/docs/html-to-pdf There is also very good documentation